# Cursor jumps backwards when typing; solutions to disable touchpad while typing don't work

Tags: touchpad, dell, cursor

I have a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 7579 2-in-1. I've tried running both the following: USB Flash Drive with 17.04, USB external hard drive with 16.04 LTS. In both the cursor jumps backwards or forwards when typing often, and seems to sometimes do a click too. I'm using external devices because I want to make sure ubuntu will work or I'll return the computer.

Tried the `Syndaemon` and touchpad app solutions to disable the touchpad while typing; they don't do anything (although I did have one moment where I was able to disable while typing using syndaemon somehow and then the cursor froze and when I restarted and tried again couldn't get it to disable again) , so I suspect they don't work because there are two touchpad devices which are getting confused as described in this post: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2316240.

The solution described looks promising which is to disable a second touchpad device. I tried the first step of opening Xorg config file in terminal by entering the following:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
```

and when I do this message appears:

```
bash: /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf: Permission denied
```

Not sure what I'm missing. I would like to try this solution if possible!

I'm not too well-versed in the inner workings of using terminal in ubuntu. Please let me know if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Permission denied` error is because you don't have the right permissions for your user. You will need to run your command like so:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
```

You can substitute the editor you normally use for `gedit`

Comment: Thank you!  That worked to open it.  I then pasted the code and got the following message in terminal: ** (gedit:6473): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported.  Also "coding" an "position" not supported.

Comment: I had entered: # Disable generic Synaptics device, as we're using
# "DLL0704:01 06CB:76AE Touchpad"
# Having multiple touchpad devices running confuses syndaemon
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchProduct "SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

Comment: You probably want to open a new question for that error. If this answer helped you solve the original error, you click on the check to the left to accept it as the solution.